# Deploying Telegram bot service to a shared host environment

Tags: webhooks, telegram-bot

I want to run a Telegram bot service in a shared ASP.NET MVC host (Plesk). There is no access to the server.

Is there any way to use bot service on a shared ASP.NET host, without buying a dedicated server or VPS, or we have to use webhooks like ASP.NET webhook?
 If so, is that the only possible way to deploy an ASP.NET bot service to a shared host environment?

Comment: simlest way is using code inside your project like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48419888/9248383

Comment: simlest way is using code inside your project like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48419888/9248383

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy to Google's [AppEngine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) that [supports .NET](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/) and has [free quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Safety_Quotas_and_Billable_Quotas).